# Progress bar at right side becomes empty in checkout process

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout

My requirement is to customize the Onepage checkout process and adding a new step between the “Payment Information” and “Review” Steps.

I have succefully added the tab but when I move to that tab the progress bar becomes empty.Please help me to solve this issue
[image: Image to show the issue]

Comment: The most common reason for that are differences in DIV ID name between JS and HTML. They were changed in some version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE:***

This is an issue with the checkout.steps variable in the checkout.initialize method.  You should add your custom step to the array of steps like so:

```
checkout.steps = ["login", "billing", "shipping", "shipping_method", "payment","exempt", "review"]
```

Comment: Everything is running the issue just occurs when I click next after selecting payment method.

Comment: And there are no errors in the console?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to add the custom step?

Comment: $result['update_section'] = array(      'name' => 'payment',); No errors in  console too.

Comment: Can you share the javascript you wrote for this?

Comment: It is written in savePaymentAction() inside onepagecontroller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20420/discussion-between-tyler-craft-and-indiesinc).

Comment: @IndiesInc were you able to get this working?